# Select objects using the keyboard instead of using the Left Mouse click

Tags: shortcut

I know I can use the up and down arrows (if the mouse focus in the outliner window) to step through objects, but that does not actually "select" the object the way a Left mouse click does.

Is there an Object mode keyboard shortcut that mirrors what a left mouse click does to actually select an object?

Alternatively, if there is none, and if need to create a keyboard mapping to replicate a left mouse click what **label/name** should I be looking for in the preferences setting to be able to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by "does not actually select the object the way a left mouse click does"? i see it is selected in yellow outline like when left clicked. so what exactly did you find is different? please demonstrate.

Comment: create 2 cubes. move one; notice transform numbers of this moved (Cube#1). Compare them to unmoved Cube (Cube#0), both have diff transform data. Now, use the LMB to click Cube#0. Then use the keyboard to change the selection from cube#0 to #1.  Notice that although you have "Highlighted" cube#1, the data in the transform window still is from Cube#0.  But if you now use the LMB to click Cube#1, the transform numbers will now change show the data for Cube#1.  How to use the KBD to do what the LMB did in the last step?  KBD arrows seem to Highlight obj's, not "SELECT" them like LMB does.

Comment: what version are you using? i'm using 3.0 and it works fine. so this looks more like a bug.

Comment: This also works fine for me in 3.2.0.  
In the keymaps, type "up" in the Key-Binding search and find "Walk Select" in the Outliner section, should be set to "Keyboard" - "Up Arrow"

Comment: this is in version 2.83...  I'll update, hopefully that will fix this.